# Why Hulk didn't get teleported away in World War Hulk?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk, doctor-strange

In *World War Hulk* we see that Hulk could beat almost anyone that stands in front of him. His physical strength is enough to draw against The Sentry, but why did no-one try to do something using magic not to defeat him, but to carry him away very very far so everyone can prepare if he reappears again? For example, someone like Doctor Strange.

Comment: IIRC, Dr Strange tried to summon a demon through his own body to fight Hulk but Hulk just smashed the demon (and thus Dr Strange) easily ? So After that Dr Strange was K.O.

Comment: Bad tactic IMHO since he could have (easily?) tried teleporting Hulk

Comment: [That’s kind of how they got into this mess in the first place.](http://marvel.wikia.com/Planet_Hulk)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To answer your question, consider the situation.  They had **ALREADY** sent Hulk very far away, to a distant planet.  When he came back, it was as that planet's **WARLORD**, with an army at his back.

In comics, magic is essentially a tool.  It can do many, many things, but it can be overcome.  Hulk, at this point, is not simply angry.  He's intelligent, focused, and out for vengeance.  Recall - he's come back because (so far as he's aware) Earth and its metahumans have taken virtually everything he cared about from him.  His home, his love, his future, everything.  He is entirely committed to destroying them.

Hulk's strength is great even in normal situations, and increases the angrier he gets.  When he finally lands on Earth, his rage is so great that the comics indicate that he could have shattered the planet with a single stomp.  This strength, since he gained Banner's intellect while in Hulk form, has also reinforced his will.

It's highly likely that any magic that could be resisted by physical strength or willpower would have washed off of Hulk like water off of a duck.

To your specific point about teleportation, please consider the situation: Hulk had an army that didn't have former relationships with Earth's heroes.  If they couldn't beat Hulk physically, their only chance at victory would be to talk him down.

Had they teleported him away, what chance would they have had?  The army would still be there, and would be hungry for blood - their beloved leader would have been seemingly destroyed by their enemies.  They wouldn't have stopped and said, "What did you DO?!"  They would have smashed and conquered.

Moreover, even if they had defeated the army after teleporting Hulk away, what would it gain them?  The last time they sent Hulk away from Earth, look what happened.  Unless they were prepared to kill him (say, by teleporting him into a star or black hole or similar) they'd risk him coming back again, possibly with more resources and ready for their tricks.

If they'd been willing to kill Hulk, they likely would have done it already (say, by having that ship crash into a star).  I believe they are unwilling to kill Hulk (as he has saved their lives many times) and, more practically, uncertain that they COULD if they tried.

Comment: I'm convinced Hulk could survive being tossed into a black hole or being throwing into a star, a nuclear explosion generates more heat than a star and gamma bombs even more so, Hulk has stood in the heart of both. Teleporting his head from his shoulders, that would kill him!

Comment: @Nullbreaker: Yeah, if the mage has a weaponized teleport that Hulk can't resist.  And sure, he can deal with the **heat**, but the point of a black hole or star isn't the heat, it's the pressure and the gravity.  The sun's gravity is so strong that is pulls the ENTIRE EARTH towards it.  Hulk can't lift the Earth (though he could shatter it), so he can't out-power the gravity of the sun.

Comment: @Jeff Hulk has survived black holes with ease and he's had a star dropped on him, lifting the Earth is no challenge. According to Marvel's fact files Hulk is still the strongest Earth based character which means he's stronger than Thor and Hyperion. Thor has lifted 20 planets in the past and in Avengers we saw Hyperion catch a planet travelling at 500,000mph.

Comment: The hulk can regenerate from a single cell so removing his head would not kill him.